# Изменения страницы ajax webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Есть страничка, которую загружаю через webbrowser. Так вот я через InvokeMember имитирую клик по кнопке, кнопка меняет свой текст после нажатия на нее, но после того как я пытаюсь вытащить текст кнопки, мне показывает старый текст. Хотя в окне браузера текст уже новый, причем иногда все срабатывает нормально, а иногда нет.

Comment: Код нужно вставлять

Comment: А еще можно обернуть проверку текста в `setTimeout`. Ой нет, в `Timer`.